# Import 'file not found' error. Why?

Tags: import

I'm trying to import a file, and for that I'm using the following code:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\William Wallace\\Desktop\\ISEG\\Séries Temporais\\TSA-Cryer and Chan\\Datasets\\hours.dat"]
```

and I get the warning "Import::nffil: File not found during Import.". However, I'm sure the file is at that directory...

If I move the file for example and try this instead

```
Import["D:\\hours.dat"]
```

I'm now able to import the data. So, what is the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the command `FileExistsQ["C:\\Users\\William Wallace\\Desktop\\Ivo\\ISEG\\Séries Temporais\\TSA-Cryer and Chan\\Datasets\\hours.dat"]` returns `False`?

Comment: What OS / version? Your path name is not above the 256-character mark, so it shouldn't be too long for Windows to handle. I wonder if the `é` character is the troublemaker here. Could you temporarily rename your path to remove the special character, out of curiosity? Alternatively, can you import *other* files from the same directory?

Comment: I'd guess that accent `e` is causing the problem.  Try this: `FileNames["hours.dat", "C:\\", Infinity]`. It will take a while but should return the full path with non-ascii characters escaped as needed.

Comment: @george2079 - a quicker way to nail down if that is the problem would be `FileNames["C:\\Users\\William Wallace\\Desktop\\Ivo\\ISEG"]` and see how the `Séries Temporais` folder name is displayed

Comment: Also, is the ["Insert File Path"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InsertAFilePath.html)  no longer a menu item, or just for my Linux installation?

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for the comment. I tried that but it still didn't work. So, I tried also removing the '-' in "TSA - Cryer and Chan", and now it works

Comment: Another approach to this is to evaluate `SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]` and navigate to the file in the system dialog, and review the string that gets returned.

Comment: @JasonB thanks for your comment

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your comment ;)

Comment: @JasonB I have "Insert File Path" on my 10.1 / redhat linux.  (and it works..) Funny I so rarely look at the menus I didn't even know it was there..

Comment: @george2079 - I just found it on the web while searching for this post, and then noticed [it isn't in my Insert menu](http://i.imgur.com/X408XaT.png)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: If you found a solution which works with the help of other users comments it would be appreaciated if you self-answer your question and accept it. For a good answer you even might get some additional reputation...

Comment: @JasonB Regarding the Insert -> File Path, so the picture you linked is not from your own system? Because I can clearly see the File Path option there, right under Horizontal Line :-)

Comment: @MarcoB, um, okay, I think I've lost my computer privileges for the week.  :-(

Answer (score 4):

Well, after reading the comment by george2079, and removing the 'é' character, the import command still returned the same error. So, I decided to remove also the '-' from the 'TSA - Cryer and Chan' folder, and it worked.